# Log4j2 Syslog Appender adds garbage field

Tags: log4j2, syslog

I'm using log4j2 to send the log messages to a remote syslog server.
The appender configuration is:

```
<Syslog name="CLSYSLOG" host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="514" protocol="TCP"   facility="LOCAL4" format="RFC5424" appName="CEP" id="ES" includeMDC="false" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" messageId="Audit" mdcId="mdc" />
```

The message makes it to the remote server but a garbage string of "fe80: 0:0:0:801:24ff:fe62:8910%2" is added after the application name in all the messages.

Any idea how can I get rid of that string?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the IPV6 address of the source. Configuring syslog replaced it with the regular IP Address.